# Visual Studio 2008 on Windows x64 Installation error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, 64-bit

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 x64 machine and I am unable to install it and don't want to give up Windows 7.

Below is the error log.

[11/05/09,15:21:08] Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit Prerequisites (x64): [2] e:\setup..\wcu\64bitprereq\x64\vs_bsln.exe could not be unpackaged because it is not a cabinet.

[11/05/09,15:21:09] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.

[11/05/09,15:21:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit Prerequisites (x64) is not installed.

Comment: Can Visual Studio be installed in a 64bit operational system once there's no VS 64?

Comment: I know that others have been able to get Visual Studio running on Vista and XP x64 machines.

Comment: I've always been able to install the 32 bit version on Vista x64 and Win7 x64, but last time I installed it I installed the 64 bit version (yes, there is one, but it's a little harder to find. I got it off MSDNAA) because I needed to compile a 64 bit Python module that had native code bits that required VS. Maybe you could try that.

Comment: I have a MSDN license and checked for a 64 bit version of Visual Studio but never could find one.   Does anyone know of where to download it?

Comment: A 64-bit version of Visual Studio does NOT exist (http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx). What Visual Studio does have is 64-bit components, e.g. 64-bit (cross) compilers, libraries, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that your installation-medium is corrupt? If you downloaded it, can you verify its checksum?

Comment: I went and found a physical disc that I knew that worked.  I had downloaded the file from MSDN using the Microsoft Download Manager and I thought that it verified the check sum but it does not.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error while attempting to install VS2008 Professional on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit). I tried clearing %TEMP%, completely uninstalling SQL Server 2008 R2 and all its shared components, but still no luck. I did a hash check on the SHA1 of the ISO I was using, which I had downloaded directly from MSDN. The SHA1's matched.

So FINALLY I went ahead and just downloaded another copy of the ISO, just for kicks. Well, it actually worked! Don't ask me why the first ISO never worked, as I said the SHA1 matched. But for some reason, the second time I downloaded the ISO, it worked.

Sorry I don't have a more rational solution, but it seems others on MSDN have had a similar success story.

Comment: Exact same thing here. A re-download of the ISO did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to any other version of VS is installed. uninstall any other version install it